# Not able to create listener rule in AWS ELB for redirect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a listener configured for my Application load balancer on `HTTPS:443`. I have 5 rules configured based on `path` which all work fine.

Now, I want to create a new rule based on `host` to redirect `www` host requests to `non-www` host e.g [www.xyz.com](http://www.xyz.com) -> xyz.com. This seems pretty straightforward but the save button for then condition is disabled. I am confused why. Please point out if I am missing something.
[image]

Comment: You are missing Redirect to -> HTTPS -> PORT. Put the port number.

Comment: Yupe, thanks it worked. but it is little confusing that if they can put default values for other fields why not the port. But thanks this was not very intuitive, you saved me the time and frustartion.